# Is there any need for authentication for a publicly accessible REST API - GET only

Tags: rest, security, lumen

I built a micro API using Lumen that only has one singular GET method, which returns JSON data from a database.

I added a simple middleware that forces the GET request to have "?key=[secretPassword]" in the URL so only people I give the key can perform the GET.

This is my first API - is this enough security measures?

edit with more info: 
The data is not sensitive and i wouldn't care if people found it but I am going to move the key into the headers for extra protection, and i am using HTTPS.

Comment: the strict answer is - its up to you, you are writing the API. The secondary question is - i need api auth (if thats what you decide) is this the right way to do it?

Comment: if you want api auth then there is no debate (if this is a real use case) - use oauth. Its not hard to do

Comment: OAuth is probably overkill for this. Basic Auth over HTTPs is more than enough.

Comment: @pm100 turns out there was a debate =)

Comment: @Evert - lol - so it seems. I just think REST API designer should get into good habit form day 1. Inventing your own security technology 'cos its just me getting started' is the slippery slope to 'we will fix that later',...'oops we just lost 10,000,000 user records'

Comment: I don't disagree that OAuth2 (or at least Bearer) is a very good default. The 'no debate' bit just made me laugh because it was immediately followed by a disagreement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I added a simple middleware that forces the GET request to have "?key=[secretPassword]" in the URL so only people I give the key can perform the GET.

It's hard to give a complete answer, because there's a few unknowns, but I'm giving it a shot.

Some notes about this approach:

- Generally it's not advised to put secrets in a url, because urls end up in caches and logs.
- You definitely need HTTPS. Without HTTPS, others can listen in on the HTTP requests and responses.
- How are you going to get this key to your end-users? Do you have some secure way to send it to them?
- How are you creating randomly keys? There's a lot of bad ways to do this.

In the title you also ask this:

> Is there any need for authentication for a publicly accessible REST API

Well... depends on what you are trying to protect yourself against? Does it matter if anyone can call the API? Then you probably don't need auth.

Comment: Thanks for answering with so many unknowns. Very helpful. I am only giving the secret key to a few end users. The data is not sensitive and i wouldn't care if people found it but I am going to move the key into the headers for extra protection, and i am using HTTPS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Having the password on the URL leaks the password, even on HTTPS traffic. Use the Authorization header instead.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not too overhead you can put up an API gateway ( Kong , Tyk , ApiGee etc etc ) in front of your API , this will give you the flexibility to handle any type of Authentication or for that matter even more in time to come.

Generally depending on the sensitivity of information or the business case the GET API is also left open at times..